Laravel 11 - SMTP configuration - HOSTINGER
I am trying to configure the SMTP in Laravel 11 project, but I am contantly getting following error:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "noreply@myappname.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: (reason unavailable)".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: (reason unavailable)".".
with following ENV. configuration:
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_SCHEME=smtp
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My APP NAME"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="noreply@myappname.com"
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@myappname.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Test123Test+
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

I have checked the password and username milion times + I also followed the hostinger guide: (https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4305847-set-up-hostinger-email-on-your-applications-and-devices), contacted the Hostinger helpdesk, but I am still getting the same error.
If I change the SMTP configuration to mailtrap it works like a charm, but there must be something special with HOSTINGER.
I also checked the SMTP TEST TOOL, but I am still getting the same error.
Any clue, what I am doing wrong?
Thx.
PS: Domain was changed - it is just a placeholder

The Hostinger guide you link to says to use port 465, and encryption SSL (as does the first hit if you search for "laravel mail hostinger") - you're not using either of those?  If that's your real password, + is a metacharacter, it's always safest to quote those, have you tried quoting your MAIL_PASSWORD?

Yeah, it was my first try. port 466 and SSL encryption. Even the password in quotes. :(

I had the same problem, but with a different hosting provider - hmara.io. I have a vps server on ubuntu 22 + laravel 11. I wrote to support with this problem, they told me that all providers renting out vps block mail ports by default, especially sending (587).
In order to unblock you need to write a ticket to open the mail ports, I opened literally for 10 minutes and mail worked, I think on hosting will be the same way

OP says they have already talked to Hostinger support, so it seems unlikely this could be the problem ...

I did not asked direclty hostinger if they are blocking the ports :), but the suggestion from the them was: Given the persistent authentication error, consider these steps:
Re-enter Credentials: Carefully re-enter your MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD to ensure there are no hidden spaces or errors.
Encryption Method: Double-check that MAIL_ENCRYPTION is set to tls in lowercase.
SMTP Tool Settings: Ensure the SMTP tool is set to use STARTTLS for the connection.
Firewall/Network Restrictions: Check if there are any network restrictions or firewalls blocking SMTP connections.

try telnet smtp.hostinger.com 587 on your server

SOLUTON for me was quite easy, but took me quite a lot time to find it (of course w/o hostinger help desk :/ )

just changed MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com to MAIL_HOST=smtp.titan.email
and it works

hope it helps someone in the future
